# Words shuffle when Arabic and English words are in a same string

Tags: asp.net, unicode, culture

When English and Arabic words are put together in a string, words tend do shuffle as Arabic has RTL direction where as English has LTR.

I am trying to send an email and following is the Subject of my email

```
String subText = "Financial Details of  شركة اختبار were sent";
```

The email subject appears as

> were sent شركة مصنع الجـــوارب الراقيــــه . المحــدوده Financial
>   Details of

After checking some other [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613613/why-words-are-shuffled-when-i-insert-english-words-in-any-arabic-urdu-persian-te) , i decided to add invisible RLE character at the start of which supposedly stops such shuffle but still getting same shuffled version.

```
char RightToLeftEmbedding = (char)0x202B;
subText = RightToLeftEmbedding + subText ;
```

What is wrong with the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the overall writing direction applied by the software that renders the email subject is right-to-left, possibly because it has been specifically designed or configured for use with right-to-left languages such as Arabic. The result is not really shuffled but normal right-to-left rendering, where a sequence of characters with left-to-right directionality are rendered with that directionality.

Using U+202B RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING does not help, since it just explicitly asks for *right to left* direction, which is being used anyway. Instead, use U+202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks